# Cascading adds/deletes for bi-directional one-to-many relationships between same entity

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, many-to-many, openjpa

I'm modeling a bi-directional 1..* relationship between two entities of the same type. I'm using OpenJPA 2.3.0 (JPA v2.0), and the underlying DB is MySQL.

Let's say that I want to model the lending/borrowing of books between readers. So:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "READER")
public class Reader {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "borrower")
    private Collection<LendingRecord> borrowedFromRecords;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "lender")
    private Collection<LendingRecord> lentToRecords;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "LENDING_RECORD")
public class LendingRecord {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false)
    private Reader borrower;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false)
    private Reader lender;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String bookName;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String returnByDate;
}
```

A `Reader` has two collections - for borrowed books and for lent books. A `LendingRecord` stores additional information about the lent book. **I'm trying to achieve consistent synchronization between these two tables.**

- If I remove a `LendingRecord` from **one** of the two collections and save the `Reader`, then:

  - The `LendingRecord` row should be deleted from the table
  - The **other** collection should be updated to remove the `LendingRecord` as well - no dangling references!
- Similar actions should happen on adding a `LendingRecord` to any one of the collections.
- Conversely, if I delete a `Reader`, all associated `LendingRecord`s should also be deleted, and the other `Reader`s in those records should also be updated.

Is there a way to model this behavior using `CASCADE`s or `orphanRemoval`? Or is there a better schema to achieve the same behavior?

Comment: See [Object corruption](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships#Object_corruption.2C_one_side_of_the_relationship_is_not_updated_after_updating_the_other_side).